# How to Handle CSRFToken Authenticity with Django REST and React.js Relation?

Tags: django, reactjs, authentication, django-rest-framework, csrf-token

I am creating a Django REST project.
I created a custom user model in which I used *rest-knox* for token authentication. For the login and register user endpoints I used custom views where I authenticate the user's by their knox token. For password_change endpoint I used django auth's views.

Here is the problem I am facing:

- When I try password_change endpoint in browsable API; it redirects me again to login page and does nothing. However Knox token for the user is created and returned in JSON.
- When I try the endpoint in Postman it gives CSRF token error since I cannot get the CSRF token. 
  I tried to create my own front-end page for changing password and sometimes the 'csrftoken' was returned in cookie table of chrome but not all the time. Since I get the user token with JSON response I set it to cookies on React.js and reach anytime I want. Yet, get method of react-cookie doesn't work for csrftoken and it is being set as undefined. Finally I tried to use *axios* library for my post request and set default header for 'csrftoken' but couldn't see any results. The front-end 'localhost:3000/change_password/' page just redirects to itself by adding passed parameters to the end of url.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets, generics
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response
from knox.auth import TokenAuthentication
from knox.models import AuthToken
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
from .models import UserProfile
from .serializers import UserSerializer, LoginSerializer, KnoxSerializer, RegisterSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import views, decorators
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

class UserListAPI(generics.ListAPIView):

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserDetailAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'


class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):

  serializer_class = LoginSerializer

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.validated_data
    token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
    return Response({
      "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
      "token": token
    })


class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):

  serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
  queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.save()
    return Response({
      "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
      "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
    })
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
from decouple import config
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'knox',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'accounts',
    'rest_auth',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Book_Lib_Project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Book_Lib_Project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',),
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': ("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",),


    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',),
}


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
      "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
#      #"accounts.backends.EmailAuthenticationBackend",
  ]

PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
]

from datetime import timedelta
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings

REST_KNOX = {
  'SECURE_HASH_ALGORITHM': 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes.SHA512',
  'AUTH_TOKEN_CHARACTER_LENGTH': 64,
  'TOKEN_TTL': timedelta(hours=10),
  'USER_SERIALIZER': 'knox.serializers.UserSerializer',
  'TOKEN_LIMIT_PER_USER': None,
  'AUTO_REFRESH': False,
  'EXPIRY_DATETIME_FORMAT': api_settings.DATETIME_FORMAT,
}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import UserListAPI, UserDetailAPI, LoginAPI, RegisterAPI, PasswordChangeAPI
from knox import views as knox_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('logout/', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name = "knox_logout"),
    path('users/', UserListAPI.as_view()),
    path('users/<str:username>/', UserDetailAPI.as_view()),
    path('login/', LoginAPI.as_view()),
    path('register/', RegisterAPI.as_view()),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ]
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'

axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
    console.log(request.headers);
    // Edit request config
    return request;
}, error => {
    console.log(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    console.log(response);
    // Edit response config
    return response;
}, error => {
    console.log(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**ChangePassword.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
//import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import './ChangePassword.css';
import Axios from 'axios'


class ChangePassword extends Component {

    state = {
        credentials: {
            old_password: '',
            new_password1: '',
            new_password2: '',
        },
        token: this.props.cookies.get('usertoken'),
    }

    inputChanged = event => {
        let cred = this.state.credentials;
        cred[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({credentials: cred});
    }

    pressedEnter = event => {
         if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                this.changePassword();
        }
    }

    changePassword = event => {

            Axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password_change/', this.state.credentials, {headers: {
                'Authorization': `Token ${this.state.token}`
            }})
            .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    window.location.href = "/";
            })
            .catch( error => console.log(error)) 
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Login">
            <form onSubmit={this.changePassword}>
                <label>Old Password</label>
                <input type="text" name="old_password" value={this.state.credentials.email} onChange={this.inputChanged} onKeyPress={this.pressedEnter}/><br/>

                <label>New Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="new_password1" value={this.state.credentials.password} onChange={this.inputChanged} onKeyPress={this.pressedEnter}/><br/>
                <label>Confirm New Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="new_password2" value={this.state.credentials.password} onChange={this.inputChanged} onKeyPress={this.pressedEnter}/><br/>

                <input type="submit" value="Change" data-test="submit" />
            </form>
      </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withCookies(ChangePassword);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem, so here is the solution if anyone encounters with the same problem and looks here.

At first, I needed to use the domain as http://127.0.0.1:3000 instead of http://localhost:3000 because of the restrictions given in https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html (check the section named as DOMAIN). Also, making some change on setting.py file was required.

Added below information to my settings.py file

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = (
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000',
)
```

Changed my axios configuration in index.js to

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/';

axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'x-csrftoken'
```

A proper way to make a post for login page is like:

```
    Axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/', this.state.credentials).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                this.props.cookies.set('usertoken', res.data.token);    
// Used token based authentication. A token is returned from backend in JSON format.
            }).catch( error => console.log(error))
```